# PyMySQL Python 3 Django VirtualEnv MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, django, virtualenv

So I had this running yesterday when I was running the virtualenv out of my home directory.  I've ran in to this problem a number of times now without a clear answer.  I've done a lot of research on this but there seems to be no black and white answer.  Today I moved my virtualenv to `/usr/local/virtualenvs` to better manage my projects and viola, it's broken again.  `Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'` is the bane of my existence right now.  I can't seem to fix it this time.  I have even tried duplicating what I did back into my home directory and have the very same problem.  I haven't deleted any packages from my system.  I installed the very same packages in the virtualenv.  At this point I'm lost.  I've even written down the steps I took *from a fresh install* to get to a working virtualenv.  I certainly don't want to go back to a fresh install.  Please help :)

**Virtual Environment:**

```
Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS
python 3.5
django 1.10.2
pymysql 0.7.9
```

**My settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'auth',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'cogs': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'cogs',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 119, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/rtservice/serviceenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can now run `./manage.py makemigrations` from *outside of the virtualenv* by adding `import pymysql` to my `settings.py`.  How is it that I can run it outside of the venv but not inside?  How can I tell what dependencies it's using to make it work, so I can run it from inside the virtual environment?

Comment: you can't generally move virtualenvs. You have to create a new one

Comment: To be clear, I didn't actually move it.  I recreated it in `/usr/local/virtualenvs` as root, then changed it's group permissions to `:www-data`

Comment: please post the full stacktrace when you get the error

Comment: Do you want the apache logs as well?

Comment: why don't you test on the dev server before you move on to apache?

Comment: A number of reasons.  Regardless, I need to get this running in the end anyway.  Posted the stack trace.

Comment: Do I need to change all the `MySQLdb` reference in `base.py` to `pymysql`?

Answer (score 0):

Added

```
try:
    import pymysql
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
except ImportError:
    pass
```

to `manage.py` and `wsgi.py`

Now working.